# How to disable bouncing animation for pageview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

Why do my codes have bouncing animation just for six items, not 7, 8, or 9, here is the full code, I don't want this animation:

```
  Widget courtsTitle(WidgetRef ref, BuildContext context) {
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    courts = ref.watch(courtProvider).courtsByClubId;

    return SizedBox(
      height: 56,
      child: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: courtLengthCalc(ref),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: pageController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        onPageChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentPage = value),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: List.generate(courtLengthCalc(ref), (index) {
            int currentIndex = (index + currentCoachState());
            return Container(
              width:
                  currentIndex == 0 ? (deviceWidth * 0.21) : deviceWidth * 0.14,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey, width: currentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1),
                  top: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  courts[currentIndex].name,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextPage(WidgetRef ref) {
    courts = ref.watch(courtProvider).courtsByClubId;

    if (isForwardCourt) {
      pageController.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(microseconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
      currentCoachesNum++;
      courtButtonsChecker++;
    }
    isForwardCourt = courtButtonsChecker * 5 < courts.length;
    isBackCourt = courtButtonsChecker > 1;

    setState(() {});
  }

  void previousPage(WidgetRef ref) {
    if (isBackCourt) {
      pageController.previousPage(
        duration: const Duration(microseconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );

      currentCoachesNum--;
      courtButtonsChecker--;
    }
    isForwardCourt = courtButtonsChecker * 5 < courts.length;
    isBackCourt = courtButtonsChecker > 1;

    setState(() {});
  }
```